# Can you pass an 'expanded' array to a function in C# like in ruby?

Tags: c#, methods

In ruby you can do something like this:

```
def method(a, b) ... end
myMethod(*myArray)
```

So if myArray had 2 items, it would be the equivalent of this:

```
myMehtod(myArray[0], myArray[1])
```

So that in the method body, a == myArray[0] and b == myArray[1]

Can you do this in C#? (So I can have a method declared with explicit arguments, instead of just taking an array as the argument)

EDIT: I should've been more specific about the method being called.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your method can be declared to accept a parameter array, via `params`:

```
void F(params int[] foo) {
    // Do something with foo.
}
```

Now you can either pass a arbitrary number of `int`s to the method, or an array of `int`. But given a fixed method declaration, you *cannot* expand an array on-the-fly as you can in Ruby, because the parameters are handled differently under the hood (I believe this is different in Ruby), and because C# isn’t quite as dynamic.

Theoretically, you can use reflection to call the method to achieve the same effect, though (reflected method calls always accept a parameter array).

Comment: I might have to end up using the reflected thing to make it work the way I want, but this is interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you declare your function's arguments with the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(VS.71).aspx) keyword, you can pass in an array *or* an arbitrary number of individual parameters.

For instance:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] x = new int[] {1,2,3};
        Bar(x);
        Bar(10,11,12);
    }

    public static void Bar(params int[] quux)
    {
        foreach(int i in quux)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

produces

```
1
2
3
10
11
12
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't have the array "auto-expand" when passed as an argument to a C# method. One way of simulating this is writing method overloads:

```
MyMethod(int a, int b) { /* ... */ }

MyMethod(int[] c)
{
   // check array length?
   MyMethod(c[0], c[1]);
}

AnotherMethod()
{
   int[] someArray = new[] {1,2};

   MyMethod(someArray); // valid
   MyMethod(1,2);       // valid
}
```

But as a few others have already mentioned, it is simpler (and somewhat the reverse) to use the `params` keyword. In my example (and yours), you always end up having separate `a` and `b`. With `params` you always have an array to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
void MyMethod(params MyType[] args)
{
}


MyMethod(myObject1, myObject2, myObject3);

MyType[] a = { new MyType(),  new MyType() };
MyMethod(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a `PostServer(string path, params object[] objects)` method that posts json to my server.  But before I send my objects array I prepend a session token to the front of it.

```
string access_token = "<access_token>";
string url = "http://example.com";

void PostJson(string path, params object[] objects) {
    SendHttp(url + path, HttpMethod.POST, JSON.Stringify(objects));
}

void PostServer(string path, params object[] objects) {
    object[] moreObjects = new object[objects.Length + 1];
    object[0] = access_token;
    objects.CopyTo(moreObjects, 1);
    PostJson(path, moreObjects); // moreObjects will be expanded into PostJson objects
}
```

Then...
`PostServer("/greet", "Hello World!", true, 3.1415);`

Will send the json `["<access token>","Hello World!",true,3.1415]` on to my server.

Actually in practice I put `moreObjects` right into `JSON.Stringify` but you get the point.

So you can expand arrays, but you have pass an array as the only params parameter. In coffeescript you could do `PostJson(path, access_token, objects...)`, because it has an splat operator `...`.

If you tried `PostJson(path, access_token, objects)` in c# you will end up sending the json `["<access_token>",["Hello World!",true,3.1415]]`

Answer (score 0):

This is now "somewhat" possible in C# 12. They call it the "spread operator"; some other languages use the term "splat".

You just precede the array with two periods, which will expand that array into its individual elements:

```cs
int[] row0 = [1, 2, 3];
int[] row1 = [4, 5, 6];
int[] row2 = [7, 8, 9];
int[] single = [.. row0, .. row1, .. row2];

foreach (var element in single)
{
    Console.Write($"{element}, ");
}
// output:
// 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

Unfortunately it only works *inside* the new "collection expression" construct.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions